# Summing numbers in excel cell that contains text and numbers

Tags: excel

How can I SUM only numbers in cells that contains numbers and text ? I am using Excel 2010
For example :

I need to SUM 2 cells that contains data like distances or salary with suffix like 20 pounds or 20 kms ?

need to exclude kms or pounds and just sum the numbers.
Any idea?
Thanks..

Comment: Use left(), mid() or right() to get the numbers then do the maths.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think there are better ways to do this to make it more generic but if you're only dealing with a few suffixes then it's just easier to put it all in one formula.

Try this ... `=NUMBERVALUE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),"kgs",""), "pounds", "")))`

An example is shown below ...

[image: Solution]

... using `SUBSTITUTE` makes it easy to remove everything nicely.  No need to search for specific positions within the string itself.